# No route match even when route is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have just started working in rails.
I have a controller that redirects to another controller to send an email for emailid verification.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save

      redirect_to :controller => 'verify', :action => 'sendmail'
    else
      format.html { render :new }

    end
```

and this is the route in routes file 
    resources :verify
but still the program is returning an error 
**No route matches {:action=>"sendmail", :controller=>"verify"}**

This is the code of the controller to which I am redirecting

```
def sendmail
    # type = 1 for email and 2 for reseting password

    randomNumber=rand()
    verification[:value]=BCrypt::Password.create(randomNumber, :cost => 1)
    verification[:type] = 1
    if verification.save
    Usermail.registered(@verification).deliver
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your routes.rb?

Comment: You are redirecting to sendmail method, but have you registered that method in `routes.rb` file

Comment: resources :users
    resources :verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Verify` (singular) as a controller name won't easily be mapped by `resources`, instead just add a custom match

```
get '/verify/sendmail', to: 'verify#sendmail', as: :verification_mail
```

Then do

```
redirect_to verification_mail_path
```